# How do Allocators and rebind work with Containers?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, allocator

I'm learning to write my own allocator right now and I'm trying to implement it with some container classes. The problem is that I'm not really understanding how the allocator is working with the List container.

Essentially I've tried to make a very simple Allocator and List Class to get up and started. What I understand so far is that rebind will allow me to allocate for my ListNodes. Allocate and deallocate will allow me to allocate memory and will return a pointer to that memory.And construct and destruct will instantiate at the allocated memory and call destructors for a particular object.

- **How do I call my rebind so that it will allocate for my ListNodes?**
- **Do I need to have an Allocator object in my List class?**
- **Would I call my allocate and construct functions in my List Constructor and dealloc and destruct for my List Destructor?**
- **Also, can someone clarify why a rebind struct would allow me to allocate for ListNodes? Theres only a typedef in there so I'm not really understanding how it would happen.**

Feel free to add any other information about allocators you can spare me please.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```cpp
template <class T>
class Allocator{
public:

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef size_t size_type; 
    typedef T& reference;

    template<class Other>
    struct rebind{
        typedef Allocator<Other> other_type;
    };

    Allocator();
    ~Allocator();

    pointer allocate(size_type n){
         pointer p = ::operator new(n*sizeof(T)); 
         return p;
    };

    void deallocate(pointer p){
        ::operator delete(p);
        return;
    };


     void construct(pointer p, reference value){
        new(p) T(value);
        return;
    };

    void destruct(pointer p){
        p->~T();
        return;
    }      
}; // class Allocator


template<class T>
class ListNode<T>{
private:
    T val;
    ListNode<T>* next;

public:
     ListNode():val(NULL),next(NULL){};
     ~ListNode(){};

}; // class ListNode

template<class T, class Alloc = memory::Allocator<T>>
class List{
private:
    ListNode<T> *head;
    ListNode<T> *tail;
    typedef Alloc<T> A; 

public:

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef T& reference;

    List(){};
    ~List(){};
    void insert(T data);
    //.... other random functions etc

}; // class List
```

Comment: Note that `typedef T* iterator;` is wrong, since `++` on a raw pointer moves through contiguous memory in a raw array, but your `T` objects will definitely not be stored that way. You'll need to define an iterator class which is or contains a `ListNode` and all its operations.  (`boost::iterator_facade` or `boost::iterator_adaptor` can do lots of the work for you.)

Comment: A bit off-topic, but in C++11, we should access allocators using [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). And C++11 much loosened the restrictions of an allocator. For example, in your case, `rebind` is not needed, `typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<T>` will do that for you.